# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_dance'" on Google Cloud run

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, oauth, flask-dance

I've built a flask app and deployed it on Google Cloud and am getting the following error when I build, and deploy:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_dance'"
```

I use the library as so:

```
from flask_dance.consumer import oauth_authorized
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
```

The app runs fine on localhost, and the build and deploy don't report any errors (it's just when I try to access the deployment via the given url that I get this error in GCP console.

My requirements.txt looks like:

```
blinker==1.4
CacheControl==0.12.6
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cryptography==2.8
firebase-admin==4.0.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Dance==3.0.0
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.11.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-firestore==1.6.2
google-cloud-storage==1.26.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpcio==1.27.2
httplib2==0.17.0
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==1.0.0
oauthlib==3.1.0
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.14.0
spoonacular==3.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.8
URLObject==2.4.3
Werkzeug==1.0.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

and flask_dance appears there (and again, runs fine locally).

I don't know why I'm getting the module import error. Any help figuring out the root cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which runtime/environment?

Comment: Have you specified installing that module in Dockerfile? E.g. **RUN pip install Flask-Dance** or **RUN pip install -r requirements.txt**

Comment: @DanCornilescu python3

Comment: @DenisT. yes, that worked! Thank you. Added a line to copy it into the docker container, and then RUN pip install. Cheers

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I have added an answer in this thread. Since the issue is solve, please accept it for a better visibility within the community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify installing that module in **Dockerfile**:

E.g.

```
# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask-Dance
```

Or

```
# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

*See [containerizing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#containerizing) the app.*