# How do I make a Dockerfile for Cloud Run?

Tags: python, python-requests, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I am deploying and running Python Jobs to Cloud Run.  I can successfully deploy and run my jobs, and they behave as expected.

I am adding `import requests` to my job, and it is giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Which led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60599991/1889720.

I created a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install requests
```

My job still successfully deploys and runs, and I no longer receive the error.  However, my `main.py` no longer runs.  It just immediately exits:

```
Container called exit(0).
```

I get the same results of an early exit if my `Dockerfile` is simply:

```
FROM python:3
```

It feels like it overwriting something?

The addition of the `Dockerfile` is the only change I made, so I suspect I am creating my it wrong.  I have it in my `jobs` directory alongside `main.py`.

How do I correctly set up a `Dockerfile` for a Cloud Run Job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question lacks some more technical context, but I think that maybe if your Dockerfile is just:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install requests
```

It actually should have the specification of the app files to be deployed.

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install requests # (If needed)
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

If that's the case I recommend searching on how to build a proper Dockerfile.

Hope it helps. :D

Comment: Is there some more technical context I can provide to help clarify?

Comment: The context that I was looking for was: The complete Dockerfile, if there was something else. The project files tree, for correct copy of files through the Docker file and more error context.
But If my first response already helped, that's fine. But keep in mind, more info helps with the problem solving. :D

Answer (score 1):

Besides `main.py`, you have to have two files in the local folder:

### requirements.txt

Where you define the libraries and their version, according to pypi.org

```
requests==2.31.0
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080

WORKDIR /home

COPY . /home
RUN pip install -r /home/requirements.txt

CMD python3 /home/main.py
```